# Finding all legal moves in a simple board game

Tags: python, numpy

I have an 8x8 board represented by a numpy.ndarray:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

#    0 = free space
#    1 = player1's figure
```

A figure can either move forward and left, forward and right or just forward (forward means down the board in this case).

Right now I am using nested for loops in order to look through the board indexes. When I find a figure I append the board states that can be achieved by making moves with that figure to a list and then keep searching for figures.

For this example the output of my function looks like this:

```
[array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])]
```

Is there a faster way in which I can find all the possible moves for a given board state?

Comment: To get the index of the ones, you can use `a.where(a==1)` for an array `a=array(...)`.

Comment: I have tried using where() but nested for loops seem to be faster.

Comment: So maybe you can store the figure-coordinate data in a `dict` or a `set`, like `{(2,3)}` . You could also use sparse matrices, they are in a sub package of bumpy I think and they should work faster with the `where`-method.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier for memory as well as performance sake, to rather than keeping a `complete board` in the memory , keep the player figure's position in the memory. Lets take your example, player figure's location is -

player1 = (1, 4)

Let's assume , players position is denoted by `(x,y)` . Then you can compute the moves for that player at runtime (no need to keep in memory) , the possible moves would be -

1. (x+1,y)
2. (x+1,y+1)
3. (x+1,y-1)

If the player figure can circle back in the board, that is if he is at the bottom most position in the board, and then next moves would be the top most row , if that is the case, the moves would be determined by taking their `modulo` against the number of rows and columns (assuming `nr - number of rows` and `nc - number of columns` ) . Example , for `(x,y)` next moves would be -

1. ((x+1) % nr,y % nc)
2. ((x+1) % nr,(y+1) % nc)
3. ((x+1) % nr,(y-1) % nc)